# Selenium vs Jsoup performance

Tags: java, performance, selenium, jsoup

I am doing a bit of web scraping, made with Selenium (so the use of this is not the question). When I have to identify an element (ie: to get a src attribute) should I use the Selenium internal selecting engine or should I use Jsoup (which is a lot easier). So the questione is: is the use of Jsoup so performance considerable? Should I use selenium as often as possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 12):

If you have the DOM parsed already into JSoup, then I would recommend using JSoup. It is much faster than selenium, since it does not need to bother with a "living" DOM. Selenium must always check if the element handles are still valid before doing any operations with them.

If you can, avoid selenium altogether, since its overhead is really noticeable when you do serious scraping. Selenium shines, however, if your content is dynamically generated by JavaScript in the client. JSoup can't handle this at all, since it does not execute JavaScript.

**Addendum to answer a comment**

Short answer : It depends!

Longer:
If the website you are scraping is generated by JavaScript and it does not change after generation, it is perfectly fine to access it with selenium, especially, if the DOM is complex and would take long to read into JSoup, although JSoup is fairly fast. However, JSoup will generate the DOM in memory again, so if your DOM is huge you will not only have it in a memory consuming way in selenium, but also in JSoup. This may or may not be an issue in your case, but it is worth keeping in mind.

From my personal experience I would kill the selenium process as soon as possible after getting the final HTML and parse this in JSoup again, since it is as you say: Jsoup scraping is way easier than the corresponding selenium selector constructs, especially if you are sure that any changes in the DOM after the initial creation are irrelevant to your scraping.

Comment: I need Selenium because of content dynamically generated by Javascript. My question was this: after having parsed the page with Selenium and got the page, should I parse and get elements with Selenium or create a Document Object for Jsoup? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I am thinking to use something like this **Document doc = Jsoup.parse(webDriver.getPageSource());**. I am dealing with some perfomance issues looping over _Selenium WebElements_, did you implement a similar solution? Did it solve your performance problems?

Comment: @Hoper Again, it depends. Parsing HTML effectively twice brings some overhead. It still may be worthwhile, if the looping over the Selenium WebElements is extensive. Especially, if the DOM changes while you loop over the WebElements you quickly run into timing issues. Since it is not really hard to program both variants, you maybe should just measure the results and go with the faster solution